# Подскажите в чем проблема (спутниковая навигация) RINEX OBS?

Tags: gps, навигация

**В заголовке указано 7 значений, но у меня в файле их 9:**

```
7    L1    L2    C1    P2    P1    S1    S2            # / TYPES OF OBSERV


16  2 24  0 52 15.0000000  0 1R09                     
 114945096.765 7  89401793.977 6  21540656.227    21540659.250    21540654.770
        45.200          37.300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7 и 6- это информация о силе сигнала или вроде того, они не входят в заголовок